# Local Swf security problems

Tags: security, flash, load

I want to have a swf locally that loads another swf from the internet.

Flash quite wisely displays a warning requiring to whitelist the place from were the external swf is being loaded.

Now is there any way for this warning not to display?

Changing those options trough the browser is quite an hassle and Im pretty sure people 
either wont bother doing it or will just thing the app is broken.

I can see why this is in place but with the fullscreen its really annoying.

Can the Flash Settings Manager be displayed inside the swf?

Comment: You should add some code, technical details, to your question.  What is the code you use to load the swf from the internet?  For your local swf, did you compile it with local file access or network access?  What does flash.system.Capabilities tell you about LFD vs. network access?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Flash developer so I can't tell you for sure, but I'm quite certain this can't be circumvented for the obvious reason that it's a security feature. If there are any tricks to get around it, they are likely to be eliminated in a future Flash Player update because they are circumventions of a security feature. So probably: No way.

I don't know your situation and whether this will work for you, but for "normal" cross-domain problems there is the possibility of setting up a Proxy file, e.g. based on PHP. Instead of calling the SWF on the other server, you would call the Proxy on the same server, that would then make the call internally and pass through the Flash content. [**Here**](http://xmlrpcflash.mattism.com/proxy_info.php) is a nice blog post on the basics.